# How to stream data from dataReader to SQL using sqlbulkcopy?

Tags: vb.net

I have a requirement to create a desktop application to copy data from an oracle database to a SQL server database (the client explicitly wants this - ETL software, DTS, etc. are all out - it has to be the desktop *.exe)

As the data runs into the millions (often tens or hundreds of millions) of rows, I cannot use sqlbulkcopy(dataTable) as the size of the dataTable very quickly uses all available memory.

I'm using sqlbulkCopy(dataReader) but it is still consuming local memory.

How can I STREAM data from the reader to the sql table, without using massive amounts of local memory?

(skipping the try-catches, etc, just core code):

```
Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
Dim connString As String = "Provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=X;password=X;Data Source=X;Persist Security Info=False"
Dim cnn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connString)
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Table", cnn)

cnn.open
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

Dim sqlCnn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=X;Database=X;Trusted_Connection=True;Connection Timeout=60")
sqlCnn.Open()
Dim bk As SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy = New SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(sqlCnn)
bk.DestinationTableName = "TABLE_NAME"
bk.EnableStreaming = True
bk.BatchSize = 100
bk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0

bk.WriteToServer(dr)
```

Throws out of memory exception on local machine, regardless of batch size.  Page file usage rises before dying.
Expected the datareader to stream to sql server, hence not use much local memory

Comment: `SqlBulkCopy` itself does not buffer when reading from a `DataReader` (I've happened to have occasion to investigate it quite deeply), but the question is whether the OLE DB provider for Oracle is kind enough to also not do that. (And does the table have any large types/blobs, by any chance?) Generally, using ADO stuff in ADO.NET isn't a very good match, and the provider is definitely deprecated. Have you tried Oracle's [native providers](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/dotnet/odp.html)?

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, the data is all pretty standard (data types are decimal, datatime and varchar/string).  I hadn't looked at the native providers you linked, so i will have a look at those this afternoon and see if anything is more suitable.  Thanks for replying so quickly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Oracle does it (used to be using row_number I believe), but you might consider paging the result sets so you're dealing with a smaller number of records at a time. Of course, you need a unique key to guarantee the order can't change and the data would need to be static while processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Jeroen for the idea to use Oracle Native Providers, rather than OLE.

"Official Oracle ODP.NET Managed Driver"

The data now streams quickly (~10,000 rows per second) and doesn't overly consume local memory, exactly what I was looking for.

New code (missing out try-catch, etc, just the code):

```
'Oracle connection using ODP.Net Managed Driver
Dim factory As Common.DbProviderFactory = Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client")
Dim dbconn As Common.DbConnection = factory.CreateConnection()
Dim connString As String = "User ID=X;password=X;Data Source=X;"

dbconn.ConnectionString = connString
dbconn.Open()

'Retrieval of data from oracle
Dim dbcommand = factory.CreateCommand
dbcommand.Connection = dbconn
dbcommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table"

Dim dr As Common.DbDataReader
dr = dbcommand.ExecuteReader

'Stream to SQL
Dim sqlCnn As SqlClient.SqlConnection = New 
SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=X;Database=X;Trusted_Connection=True;Connection Timeout=60")
sqlCnn.Open()
Dim bk As SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy = New SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy(sqlCnn)
bk.DestinationTableName = "TABLE_NAME"
bk.EnableStreaming = True
bk.BatchSize = 5000
bk.BulkCopyTimeout = 0

bk.WriteToServer(dr)
```